# Is there a way in which i can search a particular substring in all rows of a column in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I have used the following code, but it does not work

ISNUMBER(FIND(B2,$A$2:$A$6$7)).

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful for us if you gave us the contents of A2 and B2. Also, your range `$A$2:$A$6$7` does not make sense. Did you mean `$A$2:$A$67` ? The extraneous $ might be your problem.

Comment: B2 is the substring to be searched in row A . and yes I erroneously put that $ in the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MATCH and wildcards:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&B2&"*",$A$2:$A$67,0))
```

to return the value we use INDEX:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$67,MATCH("*"&B2&"*",$A$2:$A$67,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it is returning true or false, could you please help me in returning the matched value of the row.